# How to clear/remove values from onblur event after the tab is changed

Tags: html, jquery

My problem is that in my registration form when it has error message and the user tries to changed tab and back again to registration the error message are still there what should I do to be able to remove the error message when I changed the tabs and when I click again the registration link?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {           
            var tabContainers = $('section.tabs > article');
            tabContainers.hide().filter('#login').show();

            $('.ultabs a').click(function () {
                tabContainers.hide();
                tabContainers.filter(this.hash).show();
                $('.ultabs a').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
                return false;
            });
        });
        function check_email() {
            var email=$("#textEmail").val();
            $.ajax(
            {
                type:"POST",
                url:"register.php",
                data: { 
                'email': email
                },
                success:function(msg) {
                    $("#checkEmail").html(msg);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
        function check_password() {
            var pass=$("#textPassword").val();
            $.ajax(
            {
                type:"POST",
                url:"register.php",
                data: { 
                'pass': pass
                },
                success:function(msg) {
                    $("#checkPassword").html(msg);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    </script>

<nav id="siteNav">
    <h1>Navigation</h1>
    <ul class="ultabs">
        <li><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="#register">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<section id="siteContent" class="tabs">
    <h1>Section</h1>
    <article id="login">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="message" colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>E-mail:</td><td><input type="email"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="message" colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td><td><input type="password"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="button"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </article>
    <article id="register">
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="message" colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td><td><input type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="checkEmail" class="message" colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>E-mail:</td><td><input id="textEmail" type="email" onblur="return check_email()"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="checkPassword" class="message" colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td><td><input id="textPassword" type="password" onblur="return check_password()"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="message" colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Re-type:</td><td><input type="password"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="button"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Where is your code that adds the error message ?

Comment: td that has a class="message"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clear the `td` on change of the tab

```
$('.ultabs a').click(function () {
   $('.message').html('');
   // the rest of your code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use a validator plugin like the one provided by Bassistance - http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ . It will handle the error messages without you getting into the nitty gritty of validation....